# Redshift Compile Time For First Time Run Queries

Tags: amazon-redshift

i am struggling with my dashboard performance which runs queries on Redshift using JDBC driver.

the query is like -

```
select <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<ANOTHER_COLUMN_NAME> as col_0_0_, 
sum(<ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.devicecount) as col_1_0_ from <table_schema>.<table_name> <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME> where <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$1 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$2 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$3 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$4 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$5 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$6 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$7 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$8 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$9 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$10 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$11 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$12 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$13 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$14 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$15 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$16 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$17 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$18 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$19 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$20 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$21 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$22 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$23 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$24 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$25 
 or <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME>=$26 
 or ........
```

The For dashboard we use Spring, Hibernate ( I am not 100% sure about it though ).
But the query might sometimes stretch till $1000 + according to the filters/options being selected on the UI.

But the problem we are seeing is - The First Time this query is being run by the reports, it takes more than 40 sec - 60 seconds for the response. After the first time , the query runs quite fast and takes only few seconds to run.

We initially suspected there must be something wrong with redshift caching , but it turns out that , Even simple queries like these ( But Huge ) takes considerable time to COMPILE, which is clear when we look into the `svl_compile` table which shows this query was compiled in over 35 seconds.

What should I do to handle such issues ?

Answer (score 1):

Recommend restructuring the query generated by your dashboard to use an `IN` list. Redshift should be able to reuse the already compiled query segments for different length `IN` lists.

Note that `IN` lists with less than 10 values will still be evaluated as `OR`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_in_condition.html#r_in_condition-optimization-for-large-in-lists

```
SELECT <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<ANOTHER_COLUMN_NAME> as col_0_0_
     , SUM(<ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.devicecount) AS col_1_0_
FROM <table_schema>.<table_name> <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>
WHERE <ALIAS_TO_SCHEMA.TABLENAME>.<COLUMN_NAME> IN ( $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11 … $1000 ) 
;
```

Comment: Hi Joe, I am planning to do this, but anyway such queries will take time to compile the query 1st time. I was thinking of having something that will re-run such queries on Redshift whenever it finds the query isnt pre-compiled, But I really doubt we can access such kind of info. To counter this, I was thinking of running such queries on routine basis , but I dont know how frequently should we do it. I would need your advice on this too on this approach or any other better approach.

Comment: We recently announced improved cold start performance. However, since your query is relatively simple the serverless compilation fleet is not able to kick in quickly enough. You may significantly benefit from using a larger Redshift instance type if that is an option (dc2.8xlarge, ra3.4xlarge, ra3.16xlarge). https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/06/amazon-redshift-now-delivers-better-cold-query-performance/

Comment: Thank You so Much @Joe, We already have dc2.8xlarge clusters. The configuration is like 3 nodes each of type dc2.8xlarge giving a total of 7.7 TB Storage. While RA3 node might definitely give us both performance and storage benefits but there is significant cost increase too. I dont think, as of now, this request will be approved by my company. 
Is there any other way to get a performance boost for cold queries ? Is the idea of warming up by running query seem like a work around ? will it be effective ?
I ran this query from workbench 1st time, then it took 34sec, the 2nd time it took <1 sec

Comment: Since Stored Procedures are PRE_COMPILED , I was thinking of concatenating all Inputs Like `WHERE` cases into a single parameter and inside the SP I will reverse the concatenation and use them with the `IN` list. Is this a viable solution ?

Comment: Redshift stored procedures are not pre-compiled. They use the same compiled code cache as normal Redshift queries but the procedure itself is not compiled like it would be in, for example, SQL Server.